# Escape special chars while generating csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

struggle to escape some chars while generating csv.

```
let csvData = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';

const rows = [
      ["name1", "city1", "some other info #"],
      ["name2", "city2", "mo',,re info"]
];
rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {
      const row = rowArray.reduce((acc: string, itm: string) => {
           return `${acc} "${itm}",`;
      }, '');

      csvData += row + '\r\n';
});

const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvData);
```

Right now then within string appears # it just ends file, does anyone has ideas how to escape special characters like `#,"'`?

Comment: Do you want those special characters escaped or removed?

Comment: just escaped those

Comment: Btw # shouldn't terminate a file. So maybe the problem is in the settings on the csv reader side? For escaping quotes you can use underscore's [escape](https://underscorejs.org/#escape) method